# Create changeable container for component

Tags: vue-component, vue.js

I develop component, but I need, what would can change the tag name of a component container.
Like this:

`<my-component tagName="section"></my-component>`

render to

`<section>... my inner component tags ...</section>`

How to make it? 
I read about render() and functional components, but create component template with

```
render(createEl, ctx){
    return createEl(ctx.props.tagName, [createEl('div', [...])])
}
```

... looks horrible and uncomfortable.

**edit:**
Something like this: 
http://jsbin.com/qozawiwumi/edit?html,output

Comment: so you want to be able to set the outer tag of the components template dynamically? If so could the 'inner component tags' be placed inside another component within that one?

Comment: to me, it is unclear what exaclty you are asking for, could you provide a (not) working sample and provide some more details?

Comment: @c01nd01r it is still unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided this question, using is="" and this.$vnode.data.tag for render custom component wrapper.
https://jsbin.com/gifesom/edit?html,output